# How to avoid moving self for trait that is implemented for references?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
trait A {
  fn a(self);
}

struct B;

impl A for &B {
   fn a(self) {}
}

struct C;

impl A for &mut C {
    fn a(self) {}
}

fn test(c: impl A) {
    c.a();
    c.a(); // use of moved value: `c`
}
```

I need to make `test()` work for `&B` and `&mut C` arguments. How should I change the function signature to do that?

Comment: For `&B` using `c: impl A + Copy` should work, but for `&mut C`, you'd need to take a `c: &mut impl A` for it to work (and also you'd likely need to reborrow manually when calling `a`, with `(&mut *c).a()`, not sure though).

Comment: I understand, definitely a limitation then that will force to duplicate logic...

Comment: If you don't want to move `self`, you shouldn't take ownership of `self` in your method, and instead accept self by, say, mutable reference.